# Is there such a thing as a "Non-Functional Use Case"?

Tags: uml, high-availability, use-case, requirements

I'm reading a System Requirements Document that was produced using Sparx Enterprise Architect. All requirements are mapped to particular Use Cases.

A few of the non-functional requirements for "high availability" are mapped to a Use Case called "Provide High Availability", marked as `<<non-functional>>`. Am fairly new to all this and struggling to decide if it makes sense for a Use Case be non-functional - hence the question.

If the answer is yes then great - but if not, I'd be interested to know people's opinions on how such requirements should map to Use Cases (if at all).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A few of the non-functional requirements for "high availability" are
>   mapped to a Use Case called "Provide High Availability", marked as
>   <>.

As the saying goes, "if the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail".  Use Cases exist to identify the value a system provides for its user(s).  So they're meant to describe functional things: stuff the system does.

So I wouldn't generally recommend capturing non-functionals in this way.  However: that's not to say they can't be captured in Use Cases. It can be very useful *within* functional use cases to specify their non-functional requirements. For example:

```
Use Case: Submit Order
{...functional description...}

Availability: 9-5 mon-fri
Volumes: 5000 peak per day
...
```

That ties the non-functional requirement directly to the function it supports.  Which makes sense - since non-functionals have no purpose or context without function.

Of course, you'll find that many Use Cases share the same non-functionals.  You don't want to duplicate, so need to find a way to factor out.  I prefer to do that in a separate document.

But there's no law against capturing in a 'Use Case'.  Whilst it violates the theory there are reasons to do it in practice: e.g. limitations of the modelling tool (can't link UCs to a document) and/or desire to keep all in one place.

Fundamentally it boils down to theory and practice.  In theory, there's no such thing as a non-functional Use Case.  In practice creating a UC to hold non-functionals might make sense.  So long as everyone understands its really just a convenient container rather than a bona-fide piece of functionality I wouldn't get worked up about it.

hth.