# Is there possible to add Non-Functional Requirement into use case?

Tags: uml, aop, use-case, aspect

I'm newbie in AOP..

The candidate of aspect is from non-functional requirement..

But, is there possible to add non-functional requirement into use case diagram?

if not, what kind of uml that I must use to design non-functional requirement?

my goal is to add logging aspect, caching aspect, and authentication aspect.. thx for your help

Comment: Often yes with 'UML Constraints'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: you can add non-functional requirements to Use Cases.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850892/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-non-functional-use-case/18855186#18855186) might help; if not please post in comments if you want more.

hth.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be deceived by the diagram's name!

### UML Use Case Diagram has following standard non-functional elements:

- Actor
- Association
- System (with common element Subsystem)
- Simple, Include, Extend and Realization dependencies
- Generalization
- Note with Anchor
- Constraint
- Containment

Only Use Case and Collaboration elements are functional ones.

Of course, on the diagram of this very common level you can borrow elements from any other diagram freely - the only limitation is that the diagram is readable.

So you can easily describe relationships and structures in Use Case diagram